# formdata.append doesnot work as expected and overwrites instead of appending with the existing value

Tags: javascript, forms, form-data

As per MDN docs 'append' adds the value and 'set' overrides the value; So the below code should ideally give me `Chris&Chris1&Chris2`; But instead I get `Chris&`

is my understanding wrong ? if so, what is the right approach to get `Chris&Chris1&Chris2`?

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('username', 'Chris&');
formData.append('username', 'Chris1&');
formData.append('username', 'Chris2');
formData.get('username')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `getAll` instead of `get`
[getAll documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll)

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('username', 'Chris&');
formData.append('username', 'Chris1&');
formData.append('username', 'Chris2');
formData.getAll('username')
```

---

`formData.getAll('username')` will return an array `(3) ["Chris&", "Chris1&", "Chris2"]`

---

You can go ahead and join it with an empty string

`formData.getAll('username').join('')` to get expected results.

---

`formData.getAll('username').join()` will give you `csv`

`Chris&,Chris1&,Chris2`